# How to break equations in between multiple cases environment

Tags: amsmath, cases

I was wondering if anyone could assist me with the the following problem: The equation below has 4 different blocks and is too long to fit on one line. Ideally I would like to break it into two and put one half below the first half. Any ideas how to do this? I've tried `\\` and `aligned` but don't seem to be getting the right results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}  \label{int_num_test}  
x_{i}  = \eta1 \times \begin{cases} 
(1 + \eta8(age - 5.4)) & age \le 10\\
(1 + \eta9(age - 5.4)) & age > 10\\ 
\end{cases}
\times
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{Case 1}\\
1 + \eta12 & \text{Case 2}\\
1 + \eta13  & \text{Case 3}\\
1 + \eta14 & \text{Case 4}\\
\end{cases}   \times 
\begin{cases}
1 & Case 5\\
1 + \eta10 & Case 6\\
\end{cases} \times 
(1 + \eta11(v - 5.08))
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm a couple of alternatives here, neither particularly readable, I'd be tempted to define variables for the case terms and then just show it as `a\times b\times c \times d` but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\age{\mathrm{age}}

\begin{equation}  \label{int_num_test}  
\begin{split}
x_{i}  = \eta1 \times \begin{cases} 
(1 + \eta8(\age - 5.4)) & \age \le 10\\
(1 + \eta9(\age - 5.4)) & \age > 10\\ 
\end{cases}
\times
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{Case 1}\\
1 + \eta12 & \text{Case 2}\\
1 + \eta13  & \text{Case 3}\\
1 + \eta14 & \text{Case 4}\\
\end{cases} \\
  \times 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{Case 5}\\
1 + \eta10 & \text{Case 6}\\
\end{cases} \times 
(1 + \eta11(v - 5.08))
\end{split}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}  \label{int_num_testq}  
\begin{gathered}
x_{i}  = \eta1 \times \begin{cases} 
(1 + \eta8(\age - 5.4)) & \age \le 10\\
(1 + \eta9(\age - 5.4)) & \age > 10\\ 
\end{cases}\\
\times
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{Case 1}\\
1 + \eta12 & \text{Case 2}\\
1 + \eta13  & \text{Case 3}\\
1 + \eta14 & \text{Case 4}\\
\end{cases} \\
\qquad  \times 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{Case 5}\\
1 + \eta10 & \text{Case 6}\\
\end{cases}\\
\qquad\qquad \times 
(1 + \eta11(v - 5.08))
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, I'll consider re-defining variables. Do you mind explaining what `\newcommand\age{\mathrm{age}}` does?

Comment: @John it just defines `\age` to be `\mathrm{age}` to save writing `\mathrm{age}` every time, never use math italic for multi-letter words the font is designed with wide sidebearings to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word but as the product `a*g*e`.